# what is canvas.beginMarkedContentSequence

Tags: java

in our project we are stop using iText ( I think cost issues) so we have found openPdf https://github.com/LibrePDF/OpenPDF

i replace all the imports and it is compiling except this code
this is not compling

```
    canvas.beginMarkedContentSequence(PdfName.ARTIFACT); // not compling PdfName.ARTIFACT does not exists
```

can any one explain to me what this code is doing and what value i should put in

```
 PdfName.???
```

https://javadoc.io/static/com.github.librepdf/openpdf/1.3.6/com/lowagie/text/pdf/PdfContentByte.html#beginMarkedContentSequence-com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfName-

the PdfName in openPdf have all kind of value but I dont have a clue what they mean

https://javadoc.io/static/com.github.librepdf/openpdf/1.3.6/com/lowagie/text/pdf/PdfName.html

this is the full code

```
public void onEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(3);
        try {
            table.setWidths(new int[] { 450, 50, 2 });
            table.setTotalWidth(520);
            table.getDefaultCell().setFixedHeight(24);
            table.getDefaultCell().setBorder(Rectangle.TOP);
            table.getDefaultCell().setBorderColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
            table.getDefaultCell().setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
            table.addCell(new Phrase(misparMislaka + " : הקלסמ דוק / " + misparMezaheLakoah + " : חטובמ רפסמ / " + date + " : הרבעה ךיראת ", font));
            table.addCell(new Phrase(String.format("Page %d of", writer.getPageNumber()), font));
            PdfPCell totalPageCount = new PdfPCell(total);
            totalPageCount.setBorder(Rectangle.TOP);
            totalPageCount.setBorderColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
            table.addCell(totalPageCount);
            PdfContentByte canvas = writer.getDirectContent();
            canvas.beginMarkedContentSequence(PdfName.ARTIFACT); // not compling PdfName.ARTIFACT does not exists
            table.writeSelectedRows(0, -1, 36, 30, canvas);
            canvas.endMarkedContentSequence();
        } catch (DocumentException de) {
            throw new ExceptionConverter(de);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you find any solution? i just got into it.

Comment: no , we found that we can use html instaed

Comment: i got it working. i just removed  canvas.begin and end